# How to set up GTK3 in codeblocks

Tags: c++, gtk, codeblocks

I installed GTK library by following the official guide from this site https://www.gtk.org/docs/installations/windows but after I installed it
I don't know how to set it up on Code::Blocks. I need help with it.

Comment: In Code::Blocks, is there an option for "GTK+ project" if you navigate to "File" menu →"New" → "Project..."?

Comment: Probably you should [check this Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TlwWKzJFNqo).